# placing marker on specific x value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Currently, I am using matplotlib to graph two lists of extracted data from an external source. Everything graphs perfectly, however, there will always be one x value I want to mark with a star.

As of now, matplotlib puts a star on (x, y) pair from my two lists. This, in turn, makes the line look massive as it's just covered in stars from top to bottom with the only places not covered by a star generated from the matplotlib library.

After scavenging through the documentation for matplotlib I can't seem to come to. a conclusion. However, the docs did teach me how to set the marker size and the marker.

Here you can assume list_one and list_two have the same length and are just both filled with integers.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.loglog(list_one, list_two, marker="*", markersize=15)
plt.show()
```

As said previously it works perfectly fine I just can't seem to figure out how to place a marker on only one specific point on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

list_one = [x for x in range(10)]
list_two = [x+13 for x in range(10)]

spi = 9 # specific_value_index

plt.subplot();
plt.loglog(list_one[spi], list_two[spi], marker="*", markersize=15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That won't work because list_one is a list of integers. Same goes for list_two and by trying to call list_one and list_two throws an exception.

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't figure out the documentation to save my life, haha and after an hour of google searching, I decided to come here.

Comment: @Zdravstvuyte Updated. I made a bit more change to make the answer complete. Please check now.

Comment: Please consider **accepting** the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe my question is not explained well as that will not work either. I tried using matplotlibs annotate()/arrowprops() and got some good results so I might close this thread.